# Filter away grayscale colors, remove light gray, keep black

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `Mat` which is a frame containing an image of grayscale objects. I want to make everything in this image that is light gray to white, more precisely anything that is lighter than R:50 G:50 B:50 (I'm not the best with color scales, but more or less make gray objects white and keep everything that is almost black).

The grayscale is `CV_BGR2GRAY`.

I have tried to use inRange() etc. but I don't really understand how to use the channels, therefore an example with some very basic explanation is highly appreciated!

Comment: Mat1b binary = grayscale > 50;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inRange function takes the source image + 2 parameters that you should know about, lowbounds and highbounds, which are just 3-element array that cotnains the values for BGR you want the pixels to be between.
So in you case, you shall call it like this:

```
inRange(src, CvScalar(0,0,0),CvScalar(50,50,50),dest);
```